# How do i determine if 2 2d arrays are identical(meaning they have the same numbers but not same order)w/o using Arrays.equals? in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code i have gotten so far however my program says I cant convert int[] to int at at the line "for(int i:m1)"

```
public static boolean equals(int [][] m1, int [][] m2)
       {
          boolean val = false;
          int ct = 0;
          for(int i:m1)
          {
             for(int row = 0; row < m1.length; row++)
             {
             for(int column = 0; column < m1[row].length; column++)
             {
                val = false;
                for(int row2 = 0; row2 < m2.length; row2++)
                {
                   for(int column2 = ct; column2 < m2[row2].length; column2++)
                   {
                      if(m2[column2] == row2)
                      {
                         val = true;
                         ct++;
                         break;
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
           }
          }
          return val;
```

> Im using 2 classes for this program. IdenticalArrays is the other
>   class, and equals is the method within that class that determines if
>   the arrays are equal to each other. Right now my compiler is saying
>   that it cant find the symbol and hsa an arrow point to the . in
>   "IdenticalArrays.equals". Why would it not see understand what that
>   is?

```
if(IdenticalArrays.equals == true)
      {
         System.out.print("The two arrays are identical.");
      }
      else if(IdenticalArrays.equals == false)
      {
         System.out.print("The two arrays are not identaical.");
      }
```

Comment: For clarity, should each 2d array have the same frequency per number? e.g. do you want {{0,0},{0,1}} to be considered equal to {{1, 1},{0, 1}}?

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't say two arrays are identical if their values are in different orders.  What kind of definition is this?  Just curious really, I honestly don't know the answer myself.

Comment: My book has 2 different labels. Strictly Identical- whiich is all the same values in the same exact order. and Identical which means they have the same values but they dont have to be in the same order

Comment: @tyler im not sure i understand your question. Im obtaining 2 3x3 arrays from user. and determine if they both have the same numbers(dont have to be in same order) in both of them.

Comment: @BroStevens did you take a look at my answer?

Comment: @xpng yes i did. so youre main method is to sort the arrays correct? if so, imhesitant to use this as i have yet to see anything like this in my class or from my professor and dont want to to use anything that we havent learned. I actually redid my code and came up witht the same equals method as you. is the sorting absolutely necessary? like i said, my professor did not do anything with sorting the first time we had to test if 2 arrays were identical, however those were singles and these are double so idk if that causes much difference

Comment: @BroStevens I have a equals method in the bottom of my code, if you run it you will see that it does what you asked. Can you at least vote my answer up :)? Thank you

Comment: my upvotes dont publicly change :( my rep is not high enough

Comment: @BroStevens Can you mark it as the right answer then :)?

Comment: Is `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` identical to `[ [1,3], [2,4] ]` ? Is `[ [1, 0], [0, 0] ]` identical to `[ [1, 1], [1, 0] ]` ?  If any of these is true, there is actually much easier way to do.

Comment: yes they are. My code was working I just had an issue with my invocation of the class and method.

Comment: You are sure that your code works? I believe simply the `for(int i:m1)` is going to fail, not to mention other code that I don't even looked into

Comment: i redid my code but it still is having problems. If i input 2 2d arrays such as {{1, 2, 3} {2,1,2} {2,12}}, {{2,1,2}{2,1,2}{2,1,2}}. it returns that they are identical

Answer (score 0):

This should totally do what you need. Hope it helps!

```
public class Program {
static int[][] arr1 = { { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 } };
static int[][] arr2 = { { 7, 8, 9, 10, 6 }, { 15, 14, 13, 12, 11 } };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lowest;
    int switcher;
    int posX = -1;
    int posY = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < arr2[i].length; z++) {
            lowest = arr2[i][z];

            for (int x = i; x < arr2.length; x++) {
                if (x == i)
                    for (int y = z; y < arr2[x].length; y++) {
                        if (arr2[x][y] <= lowest) {
                            lowest = arr2[x][y];
                            posX = x;
                            posY = y;
                        }
                    }
                else
                    for (int y = 0; y < arr2[x].length; y++) {
                        if (arr2[x][y] <= lowest) {
                            lowest = arr2[x][y];
                            posX = x;
                            posY = y;
                        }
                    }
                ;
            }
            switcher = arr2[i][z];
            arr2[i][z] = arr2[posX][posY];
            arr2[posX][posY] = switcher;


        }
    }

    System.out.println(equals(arr1, arr2)); 

}

public static boolean equals(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    for (int x = 0; x < m1.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < m1[x].length; y++) {
            if (m1[x][y] != m2[x][y]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a clear definition on your "identical".  Let's us go through these one by one, from strictest to loosest definition:

## A. Strictest Form:

- Number Array is *identical* when numbers in one array is rearrangement of the other.
- 2D Array is *identical* when each Number Array in the 2D array can pair up with one *identical* Number array in the other 2D array, and each Number Array in each 2D array can only pair up with one Number array.  (i.e. similar to definition of Number Array, one 2D array is rearrangement of the other)
- i.e. `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` is identical to `[ [4,3], [2,1] ]`
- `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` is not identical to `[ [1,3], [2,4] ]`
- `[ [1,1], [2,3] ]` is not identical to `[ [1,2], [2,3] ]`

This can be easily done by

1. Convert each Number Array to `Map<Integer, Integer>` which store the count of each number (let's call it Normalized Number Array)
2. Convert each 2D Array to `Map< Map<Integer,Integer>, Integer>` which store count for each Normalized Number Array
3. Simply use equals to compare the two Normalized 2D Array.

## B. Looser Form:

- two 2D arrays are identical to each other if numbers in it is rearrangement of the other.
- i.e. `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` is identical to `[ [1,3], [2,4] ]`
- `[ [1,1], [2,3] ]` is not identical to `[ [1,2], [2,3] ]`

It can be easily done by

- Convert the 2D array to a `Map<Integer, Integer>` which store count of each number
- Simply compare the two `Map<Integer,Integer>`  by `equals()`

## C. Loosest Form:

- 2D array is identical as long as they contains same sets of numbers
- i.e. `[ [1,1], [2,3] ]` is identical to `[ [1,2], [2,3] ]`

It can even easier:

1. Convert the 2D array to `Set<Integer>` which stores the number appeared
2. Compare the 2 `Set<Integer>`s by `equals()`

Here is the pseudo-code for the loosest form:

```
static Set<Integer> toIntegerSet(int[][] intArray) {
    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int[] a : intArray) {
        for (int i : a) {
            intSet.add(i);
        }
    }
}

static boolean isIdentical(int[][] a1, int[][] a2) {
    return toIntegerSet(a1).equals(toIntegerSet(a2));
}
```

---

The reason your compiler is complaining is you haven't even have a correct syntax:

```
if(IdenticalArrays.equals == true)
```

should be

```
if(IdenticalArrays.equals(array1, array2) == true)
```

or even better, simply

```
if(IdenticalArrays.equals(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Im sure your code is all correct. however i at such a low level, i dont believe im allowed or supposed to even know about Set<integer>  and all that. Im pretty sure im not even supposed to use Arrays.equals for this. Because i need to learn how to code it all myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // the arrays
    int a1[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int a2[] = {2, 3, 1};

    // copy array to don't modify originals
    int[] a1Temp = Arrays.copyOf(a1, a2.length);
    int[] a2Temp = Arrays.copyOf(a2, a2.length);

    // sort the temp arrays
    Arrays.sort(a1Temp);
    Arrays.sort(a2Temp);

    // check if temp arrays are equals
    boolean test = Arrays.equals(a1Temp, a2Temp);
    System.out.println(test);

    // to large arrays, these operations have a coast 2xO(n log n)+3xn
```